# Applying Ehrenfest's theorem to Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics

It maybe a stupid question, but from the Ehrenfest's theorem, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d\langle A\rangle}{dt} &=& \left\langle\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{i\hbar}\left\langle[A,H]\right\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
The if we apply it to the Hamiltonian,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d\langle H\rangle}{dt} &=& \left\langle\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{i\hbar}\left\langle[H,H]\right\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
But since the last term vanishes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d\langle H\rangle}{dt} &=& \left\langle\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\right\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
But in general cases, the expectation value of the time derivative of the Hamiltonian is not zero, i.e. in the infinite potential well.
$$ \left\langle\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\right\rangle=\int\Psi^*\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\Psi dx=\int\sum_n c_n^* \psi_n^*e^{iE_n t/\hbar}\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\sum_m c_m \psi_m e^{-iE_m t/\hbar}dx$$
$$ =\int\sum_n c_n^* \psi_n^*e^{iE_n t/\hbar}\sum_m c_m (H \psi_m) \frac{\partial }{\partial t}e^{-iE_m t/\hbar}dx$$
$$=\int\sum_n c_n^* \psi_n^*e^{iE_n t/\hbar}\sum_m c_m{1\over{i\hbar}}E_m^2\psi_m e^{-iE_m t/\hbar}dx$$
$$={1\over{i\hbar}}\sum_n\sum_m e^{i(E_n -E_m) t/\hbar}c_n^*c_m\int E_m^2 \psi_n^*\psi_m  dx$$
$$={1\over{i\hbar}}\sum_n |c_n|^2E_n^2 $$
But since the expectation value of the Hamiltonian in the infinite well is a constant, it is obviously a contradiction. Is it impossible to apply the Ehrenfest's theorem to the Hamiltonian, or is there any mistake in my calculation?

Comment: As Robin Ekman noted, $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=0$.

Comment: You mean that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=-{\hbar^2\over{2m}}\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial t\partial x^2}$ (in the well) is zero. Am I right? But I don't get it. Why does the non-applied operator become zero?

Comment: See comment I wrote below Robin's post. Basically, you're taking the derivative of a matrix $\frac{p^2}{2m}$, rather than a matrix-vector product $\frac{p^2}{2m}\cdot\psi$. The matrix is time-independent, even though the matrix-vector product isn't. The idea that operators like $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ can be represented as matrices that are applied to functions (vectors) may seem strange, but it can be made moderately rigorous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the infinite potential well, do we not have $H = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ inside the well? Then $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t} = 0$.

I think you have misinterpreted $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$. You seem to be applying $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$ to $(\psi^* H\psi)$, but you should be applying $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$ to $\psi$, and then multiplying that by $\psi^*$.

Ehrenfest's theorem applied to the Hamiltonian is the analogue to the classical mechanics theorem that $H$ is conserved unless it depends explicitly on time.

Comment: I did apply the operators in the right order as you said in my calcaulation above. As far as I know, $p$ is the momentum operator, so, by applying $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$, we cannot make it zero since it is not a variable. Is it right? since $\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial t\partial x^2}$ is not zero but just an operator...

Comment: @dielectric: $\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial t\partial x^2}$ is not the same as $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$ (ignoring the extra factors of $i,\hbar$). It is basically the difference between taking $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\mathbf{A}(t)\cdot\mathbf{x}(t))$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix and $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, versus $\frac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial t}\cdot\mathbf{x}(t)$. Think of $p^2$ as a matrix (after all, with the appropriate choice of basis it is a matrix).

Comment: $p$ is the momentum operator, yes. But $p$ is a constant function of time. Your third order differential operator is $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \circ p^2$, as composition, not $\frac{\partial p^2}{\partial t}$ as in the time derivative of the function that assigns to every time $t$ the operator $p^2$. Since this function is constant, the derivative is 0.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: Uh... I still don't get it clearly, but you mean that I have to calculate the time derivative of the operator $H$ itself, not just to compose two operators? But how can I define the partial derivative of the partial derivative operator itself?

Comment: It is the same operator for every time, right? The derivative of a constant is 0.

Comment: @Robin Ekman Yes, that fact is very clear to me, now I understand what it "means" by $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=0$, but I don know "why" this calculation is valid... is there such a thing like $\Delta p$? Does the operators change quantatively?

Comment: The momentum operator $p$ is always the same. But suppose you had a time-dependent electric field. Then the electric potential operator is a function of $x$ and $t$. For example $\phi = E\cos(kx - \omega t)$ representing the field from an EM wave. This operator certainly changes with time.

Comment: @Robin Ekman Thank you for the example, but now I understand  that in some cases the operator can vary but cannot in other cases, but I'm still lost on the point that how can the time derivative of the derivative operator itself be defined. Just deducing 'this operator is stationary, so it's time derivative is zero.' is only an easy case, but how can I define the new operator $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$ from the Hamiltonian $H$?

Comment: $H$ is a function of the operators $p,x$ and the number $t$: $H = H(\hat p, \hat x, t)$. They are all independent. To find $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$, do as you would for any function.

Comment: @Robin Ekman Ah... it was the patial derivative, not a total derivative... I was stupid. Thank you very much for your kind explanation!

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a contradiction. The nonzero partial derivative of the Hamiltonian implies that it contains time-dependent terms meaning that the wave function can not be dependent on time just like $e^{iE_nt/\hbar}$ The dependence should be more complicated. You assume that partial derivative is non-zero and, at the same time, you take the wave functions corresponding to a stationary solution with time-independent coefficients $c_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can the parital derivative of $H$ w.r.t. time itself be 0? I mean, as far as I know, the Hamiltonian in QM is not merely a variable but an operator, so it cannot be 0 just by applying partial derivative. Am I right? And also in the stationary infinite potential well, the wave functions indeed have the time dependence like $e^{iE_nt/\hbar}$, so I think that's not the main reason that I got the contradiction...